# Cant navigate on React Native. The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-navigation

I've been stuck on this error for three days now:
"The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Login"} was not handled by any navigator."
I dont have any idea what to do. If you can help me, I would appreciate that! I think is something to do with the Navigation.Container but I really dont know. Im using firebase for the auth as you can se. I want to navigate to login after log out.

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

import Login from "./Login";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function LogOutStack() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import Home from "./Home";
import SaveAdress from "./SaveAdress";
import SaveInfo from "./SaveInfo";
import Login from "./Login";
import UserInfo from "./UserInfo";
import SelectAdress from "./SelectAdress";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import {
  getAuth,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  setPersistence,
} from "firebase/auth";
import LogOutStack from "./LogOutStack";
import SignInStack from "./SignInStack";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function AuthNavigator() {
  const [userx, setUserx] = React.useState();

  const auth = getAuth();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    check8();
  });

  const check8 = () => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
        // const uid = user.uid;
        //navigation.navigate("Login");
        setUserx(user);
        if (initializing) {
          setInitializing(false);
        }

        //navigation.navigate("Login", userx);

        // ...
      } else {
        // User is signed out
        // ...
        console.log("No user");
      }
    });
  };
  return userx ? (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={userx}>
      <SignInStack />
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  ) : (
    <LogOutStack />
  );
}

export const AuthContext = React.createContext(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Navigation.Container` isn't doing anything wrong in this case. I see you want to use `navigation.navigate`, but didn't declare the `navigation` itself. Instead in your AuthNavigator, add this lines of code:

```
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

# you forget to declare this.
const navigation = useNavigation(); 

#your navigation
navigation.navigate("Login");
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer! That line is commented. Is doing nothing. I still cant get whats wrong.

Comment: can you please tell me in detail what you want??